# Best way to create an MVC 4 Timetable/Calendar/Scheduler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, scheduler, timetable

I am new to stackoverflow, so please forgive me.

I am trying to create a student timetable for a student information system as part of a University project that will display the times, dates, details of modules as well as the location of the events.

I have done endless research and I haven't found a solution to my problem. I know there are the likes of the DHTMLX scheduler and Daypilot scheduler (Which is exactly the sort of thing I have been looking for) but these do not really suit for a number of reasons:

1. Both only offer 30 day trials and I would need it for slightly longer than that as the project is needed right up to July
2. I have tried to follow the tutorials for the DayPilot scheduler lite version but it just does not seem to load for me no matter what I try.

I have looked everywhere but nothing seems to be working for me and that's why I would love some feedback/advice if there are any other methods that I should explore.

I am using MVC 4 in Visual Studio 2012.

Thanking you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try JavaScript DHTMLX Scheduler. It is free under GPL license, which should be ok for a university project. You'll need to manually implement loading and saving of calendar data (which is done by helpers in ASP.NET version of the component), although it should be not that difficult. You can check this tutorial, it's quite outdated but still may be useful 
http://www.dhtmlx.com/blog/dhtmlxscheduler-for-net-mvc/

Note that starting from the latest version the GPL package does not include several modes, such as Timeline or Units(resources) views

However, if you need them you can grab the previus version from a GitHub https://github.com/DHTMLX/scheduler/tree/v4.2.0